# Notice: Uninitialized string offset Error

Tags: php, wordpress, string, initialization, offset

I am getting an error on a wordpress premium plugin wp Pro Ad System. Everything was perfect but suddenly updating the plugin I am having two error repeating frequently in home page where I set my ads.

The error links are as follows:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in
>   /home3/silviaknight/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wppas/classes/Pro_Ads_Banners.php
>   on line 463
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   /home3/silviaknight/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wppas/classes/Pro_Ads_Banners.php
>   on line 463

Here is the 463 line code that is indicating the error.

```
$default_size = $container_only ? 'style="width:'.$size[0].'px; height:'.$size[1].'px;'.$bg_color.'"' : '';
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Your best bet is to connect with the original author to get it fixed. With minimum code I can see, it seems that `$size` variable is now coming as `string` instead of as an `array`. Try a `var_dump` of it to confirm this.

Comment: If `$size` is `empty` then as well you'll get this error